# Power inverter batteries requirements/number

Tags: battery-charging

I am looking to install a hybrid power inverter for my home. I've done a bit of a usage test and research and it seems I just need 3.5KVA or 5000KVA at most.

My average monthly usage is 322kWh at R564.72. I basically need to know the size and number of batteries that I would need to have a few lights on and 3/4 plug points (1XTV room, 1X kitchen-fridge and 2x bedroom) on a 4hr loadshedding schedule.

According to the little research I've done, to run 3.5kVA I would need a 24V battery minimum. How many 24V/100Ah batteries would I need to have just the basic connected for 4 hours?

Comment: Should it be 5000 kVA or 5 kVA ? And 8 x  24 V / 100 Ah should be used.

Comment: Hi Antonio, thanks for the response. Should it be 3.5kva how many would I need/